# How to add a particular function from service to directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

This is a function I have added in localcacheService.
I want to add this function in directive.

```
LocalCacheServiceClear.prototype.isAvailable = function() { 
    this.cache.clear();   
}
```

My directive is this:

```
(function() {
    var MainApp = angular.module('MainApp');

    MainApp.directive('Logout', function () {
        return { 
            'restrict': 'E',
            'templateUrl': 'directives/panels/Logout.html',
            'controller': ["$scope","LocalCacheService", function($scope,LocalCacheService) {
                console.log("Logout Controller called....");

                $scope.Logout = function() {
                    window.sessionStorage.clear();
                    console.log('Log out');
                }                     
            }]
        };
    });

}());
```

How to add this function to this directive?

Answer (score 0):

via Angular Service:

```
MainAppUserConvMod.service('LocalCacheServiceClear', LocalCacheServiceClear);
```

and then inject into your directive:

```
MainAppUserConvMod.directive('Logout', function (LocalCacheServiceClear) {
```

and use it

```
LocalCacheServiceClear.isAvailable()
```